# Error installing EGIT In eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I am having some real issues installing the eGIT plugin for eclipse.

If i go to the install new software page and enter http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-nightly or http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-nightly in the work with bar i get no results - only a could not find  message.

If i change the work with to all available sites, and then search egit i get nothing.

If i try and do an update of eclipse and then search I still get nothing.

I have no idea what else i need to do! I am using Juno which apparently has it pre installed but i dont see it in the show view or persepctive window anywhere

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

window -> open perspective -> other -> git repository exploring

I entered the same link as you provided and I see the plugin. What do you see? Can you post the picture?
[image]

Comment: @SkyR are you using the "Eclipse IDE for java EE Developers" or some other? http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/   -> the first one in the list?

Comment: eclipse java ee ide for web developers juno release

Comment: added the pic to my original post

Comment: @SkyR what happens if you choose this link? http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28361/discussion-between-eugene-and-skyr)

Answer (score 1):

Your Eclipse installation simply has trouble accessing the Internet. Either your machine really isn't connected, or your proxy settings inside Eclipse are wrong. For the latter, look at Window -> Preferences -> General -> Network connections.

Comment: Thank you so much..I was troubling with egit installation from last 3 days and you made my day..its solved :)